# clearTimeout() - my code work fine with click/link; then why die when you hold down a key?

Tags: javascript

when you call the functions with LINK all work fine:

```js
function show() {
  s = new Date();
  M = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = s.getSeconds() + '.' + s.getMilliseconds();
    show();
  }, 150);
}

function stopshow() {
  clearTimeout(M);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'all stopped!';
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="sin" onkeypress="show();" onkeyup="stopshow();this.value='';" />

<a href="" onclick="show();return false;">show</a> /
<a href="" onclick="stopshow();return false;">not show</a>
<div id="output"></div>
```

also if you press ONE TIME one key.

but when user hold pressed a key, then all wrong.

why?

Comment: in `show()`, add `clearTimeout(M);` at the top of the function - think what happens if you call `setTimeout` without calling `clearTimeout`

Comment: thanks @[Jaromanda X] when I add in top: `Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you are recursively call `show()` function that make number of show() call is much larger than `stopshow`, mean many of the `setTimeout` is not cleared here. I wonder why you need to call `show()` again inside the `setTimeout`? Or `clearTimeout` right before it's called again

```js
let M

function show() {
  s = new Date();
  clearTimeout(M)
  M = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = s.getSeconds() + '.' + s.getMilliseconds();
    // remove this line
    show();
  }, 150);
}

function stopshow() {
  clearTimeout(M);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'all stopped!';
}
```

```html
<input type="search" name="sin" onkeypress="show();" onkeyup="stopshow();this.value='';" />

<a href="" onclick="show();return false;">show</a> /
<a href="" onclick="stopshow();return false;">not show</a>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks @[vicnoob] please edit your code, (return severals errors...)

Comment: @Yamile I already edit it once, still error? which one

Comment: many thanks master @[vicnoob] which is the trick?, why my code fail but your code = perfect? :-) regards!

Comment: -  Should initialize variable M first, then clearTimeout right before calling setTimeout (this is known as debounce), or just remove the show() inside the setTimeout, what's the second `show()` purpose?

Comment: all "trick" is add **`let M;`** in top?

Comment: when I remove `show();` then "timmer" only show ONE TIME (function not loop)

Comment: then I guess you need to clear the timeout right before the next timeout is added to queue

Comment: thanks again, and sorry: really me not understand your instruction. I need the function `show()` run one time and other each X microseconds; until `stopshow()` is called

Comment: @Yamile See the 2nd line of the function show() bro